# How to understand $L_{\mu}:= L+\mu I\colon H_0^1(U)\to H^{-1}(U)$ is an isomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In *Partial Differential Equations* (Evans) Section 6.2.2, the last part **Mapping $\mathbf{H_0^1}$ to $\mathbf{H^{-1}}$**, it's said that the mapping
$$
L_{\mu}:= L+\mu I\colon H_0^1(U)\to H^{-1}(U)
$$
is an isomorphism. How to understand this assertion?

Comment: I do not have the book but I would understand it as isomorphism of topological vector spaces, i. e. the map is isomorphism of vector spaces that is continuous and has continuous inverse. Is this what is your question about? From the current formulation it is not clear to me where exactly your issue is.

Comment: @Korf Let me make a verification.